# java.io.IOException: stream is closed

Tags: json, groovy, httprequest, response, rest

I am getting below error when i am trying to print response from http connection. I think i am using the stream twice and for this reason it says stream is closed but not sure.

The error is coming on the `writeInstFile()` method where i am trying to print response using `getInputStream().getText()`

I just wanted to create new string variable and put the connection stream response in that variable and print it so that i can see what response i am getting when i try to do http request:

```
    private void writeInstFile(File outFile) {
        Properties config = workflowEnvironment.getConfig()        
        //http connection to get Authentication token
        HttpURLConnection connection = connection("https://XXX/RequestToken")

        if (connection.responseCode == HTTP_OK) {
            String authToken = authTokenFromJson(jsonFromDssRequestTokenConnection(connection))
            log.info("Authentication token: $authToken")
            println(connection.getInputStream().getText());
        if (connection.responseCode == HTTP_OK) {
            println("Got http response code: ${connection.responseCode}, message: ${connection.responseMessage}")

            log.info("Successful DSS request to ${connection.getURL()}")

            LazyMap json = jsonFromDssExtractionConnection(connection)
.....
}


private static String authTokenFromJson(LazyMap json) {
        json.value
    }


private static LazyMap jsonFromDssRequestTokenConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        connection.inputStream.withCloseable { inStream ->
            new JsonSlurper().parse(inStream as InputStream)
        } as LazyMap
    }
```

Comment: `connection.inputStream.withCloseable` this line is closing your stream

Comment: yes but how to manage this ..as i just to print the response from stream...like i am printing authToken

Comment: try printing belore the call of `jsonFromDssRequestTokenConnection` method

Comment: i have edited method writeInstFile() and trying to print like this and now i got the response but still issue coming  CAUSE java.io.IOException :: stream is closed
i thinksame like authToken cant we create variable and put the response in string ?

Comment: `connection.getInputStream().getText()` closes input stream and after this you try to read from it again `connection.inputStream.withCloseable`. you can read http response only once.

Comment: yes but what if i put into string and try to read the string as response ?

Comment: should be fine.

Comment: But how to do that i am not sure ?